# Javascript - removing negative values in an array only using the pop() method

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to remove the negative numbers in this array using only the pop() method in Javascript. I know pop() removes the last item so how would I use pop() to remove both negative numbers in this array? Thank you!

```
var x = [-3,5,1,3,2,10,-7];
for (var i = x.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
  if (x[i] < 0){
    x.pop(x[i]);
  }
}
console.log(x)
```

Comment: Does it have to be that array, and only the pop() method, because you can sort the array to relocate negative numbers to the end and then use pop() to remove them

Comment: Why are you restricted to `pop()`? Because unless you can use other methods to manipulate the array, this can't be done. What are the actual restrictions? And, regardless of whether this is homework or not, can you show your attempt to remove the first negative number?

Comment: This is a silly question.  `.pop()` removes the last item in the array ONLY.  It does not take an index as an argument to remove that specific item.  There are methods like `.splice()` for removing specific items.

Comment: *"how would I use pop() to remove both negative numbers in this array"* You  wouldn't.

Comment: Here are the instructions I was given: (Removing Negatives) Given an array X of multiple values (e.g. [-3,5,1,3,2,10]), write a program that removes any negative values in the array.  Once your program is done X should be composed of just positive numbers.  Do this without creating a temporary array and only using pop method to remove any values in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find this a rather silly question to only use `.pop()`.  It smells like homework and is NOT a real-world question in any way.

---

OK, now that the actual rules have been disclosed (only use `.pop()` for removing values and no temporary arrays), here's a method that uses only `.pop()` to remove values from the array.  It assumes that the original order does not need to be preserved (though that could be done with more code).  This works backwards through the array and any time it finds a negative value, it swaps that value with the last value in the array and then `.pop()` off that negative value:

```
var x = [-3,5,1,3,2,10,-7], temp;
for (var i = x.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (x[i] < 0) {
        if (i !== x.length - 1) {
            // swap current value with last value
            temp = x[i];
            x[i] = x[x.length - 1];
            x[x.length - 1] = temp;
        }
        x.pop();
    }
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/wo8fhoor/

---

And, here's a version that preserves the order of the array while using only `.pop()` to remove items from the array.  When it finds a negative value, it copies down all the subsequent items after it in the array (thus removing it) and then uses `.pop()` to shorten the array by one:

```
var x = [-3,5,1,3,2,10,-7];
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i] < 0) {
        removeItem(x, i);
    }
}
log(x);

function removeItem(array, index) {
    for (var i = index; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        array[i] = array[i + 1];
    }
    array.pop();
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/uvqx6hq0/

---

These versions of code came before the full rules had been disclosed

You can cycle through the array, popping off the last item each time and then build a new array with only the values you like:

```
var x = [-3,5,1,3,2,10,-7];
var y = [];
while (x.length) {
    var val = x.pop();
    if (val >= 0) {
        y[y.length] = val;
    }
}
x = y.reverse();
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/2atz6ck9/

`.pop()` only removes the last item in the array.  It does not take an argument to remove that particular item so you can't use it to remove the nth item in the array.

---

In the real-world, you would either use `.filter()` to generate a new array or you would use `.splice()` to remove individual elements.

Here's a `.splice()` solution:

```
var x = [-3,5,1,3,2,10,-7];
for (var i = x.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
  if (x[i] < 0){
    x.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
console.log(x)
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/gqt5avLb/

---

And, here's a solution using `.filter()`:

```
var y = x.filter(function(val) {
     return val >= 0;
});
```

Or, in ES6:

```
let y = x.filter(val => val >= 0);
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I did it with splice and worked to create an empty array and then push the positives into that new array, I just can't figure out how I would use pop and no temporary arrays. Here are the instructions i was given: (Removing Negatives) Given an array X of multiple values (e.g. [-3,5,1,3,2,10]), write a program that removes any negative values in the array.  Once your program is done X should be composed of just positive numbers.  Do this without creating a temporary array and only using the pop method to remove any values in the array.

Comment: @bschmitty - it would have helped things tremendously if you had disclosed the actual rules when you wrote your question.  Now that you have, I've added two methods to the start of my answer that use nothing but `.pop()` for removing items from the array.

Comment: thanks for the help. That makes sense in swapping the current value with the last value if the negative number is not the last item. Can you explain the function in a little bit more detail:function - in the removeItem function, what arguments are you passing into the two parameters - (array, index)?

Comment: @bschmitty - `removeItem(array, index)` takes the array you want to operate on and the index of the element in the array you want to remove.  It then copies down (one slot in the array) all the values after that one in the array and then uses `.pop()` to remove the last item.

Comment: @bschmitty - Since it looks like you are perhaps new to StackOverflow, are you aware that if you get your question answered, then you should select the best answer and click the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  This will inform the community that your question has been answered and earn both you and the person supplying the answer with some reputation points.

Comment: same answer using es6 
`valor = valor.filter(n => n >=0)`

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that you want using the `filter` function.

```
var positiveNumbers = x.filter(function(number){ 
       return number>=0;
})
```

```js
var x = [-3,5,1,3,2,10,-7];

var positiveNumbers = x.filter(function(number){ 
       return number>=0;
});

document.write(positiveNumbers);
```

Using the `pop` method that you try is not possible. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

> The pop() method removes the last element from an array and returns
>   that element.

Furthermore, you can't *simultaneously* try to iterate through the elements of an array and removing elements from this array. It doesn't make sense. You can filter the elements of an array, you can remove specific elements, you can add elements to an array but you definetely you can't looping through it's elements and at the same time to remove elements from it.

Comment: This is true (and a far better approach), but it definitely doesn't meet the "*using only the pop() method*" restriction.

Comment: @DavidThomas thank you. One question. Is this possible at all? How can he loop through an array and in the same way remove values of this array? I don't think that this is possible. Correct?

Comment: No, it's not possible (unless the restriction to `pop()` is arbitrary and 'some' other array methods are available as well).

Comment: Shouldn't it read: `return number >= 0`? Otherwise it will fail horribly if zero should be allowed in the future as well.

Comment: *"you can't looping through it's elements and at the same time to remove elements from it."* I disagree: `for (var i = arr.length; i--;) }{ arr.pop(); }`

Comment: @FelixKling isn't this an edge case? If I understand your code, in each step we pop up the last element of the array. At the end the array would be empty. Correct? Could we do the same for the scenario of OP ?

Comment: @Christos: No idea if that would be helpful in that case. I'm just saying that you can iterate over the array and remove elements from it (the end) if you do it backwards.

Comment: Here are the instructions I was given: (Removing Negatives) Given an array X of multiple values (e.g. [-3,5,1,3,2,10]), write a program that removes any negative values in the array.  Once your program is done X should be composed of just positive numbers.  Do this without creating a temporary array and only using pop method to remove any values in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use a 2D array.

```
var x = [1, -2, 3]; //Your basic array
var x1 = [[1, -2, 3], [-2, 3, 1] ,[3, 1, -2]];
//Perhaps put this into a function?
for (var i = 0; i < x1.length; i++) {
  if (x1[i][x1.length] < 0) {
    x1[i].pop();
    return x1[i];
  }
}
```

This is by no means an efficient solution, but if you have small numbers of elements it should be fine.

**EDIT:**

Here is a function for the creation of the 2D Array:

```
var createArray = function() {
  var x = [1, -2, 3]; //Your array here
  var x1 = []; //The 2D array
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x1[i] = []; //Makes the 2D array
  }
  x1[0] = x; //The first array
  for (var i = 0; i < x1.length; i++) {
    var last = x1[i].pop(); //Finds the last element
    x1[i+1][0] = last;
    for (var j = 0; j < x1[i].length; j++) {
      x1[i][j] = x1[i+1][j+1];
    }
  }
  return x1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var x = [-3,5,1,3,2,10,-7];
var arr = x.map(function(item, index) {
    return [item, index]; // Add indices
});
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b[0] - a[0];   // Sort by value
});
while(arr[arr.length-1][0] < 0)
    arr.pop();            // Pop negatives
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[1] - b[1];   // Undo sort
});
arr.map(function(item) {
    return item[0];       // Remove indices
});
```

Of course, that's not a good way to remove negatives.

Answer (score 0):

This *is*, despite my previous comments, possible with `pop()`, but it requires the creation of another array, while iterating over the existing array:

```js
function ridiculousApproach(arr) {
  if (!arr) {
    return false;
  }
  var temp = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    temp.push(arr[i]);
    if (arr[i] < 0) {
      temp.pop();
    }
  }
  return temp;
}

var x = [-3, 5, 1, 3, 2, 10, -7];

console.log(x, ridiculousApproach(x));
```

This is, however ridiculous, since it'd be easier, and far more sensible, to not add the negative numbers to the `temp` array in the first place:

```js
function ridiculousApproach(arr) {
  if (!arr) {
    return false;
  }
  var temp = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > -1) {
      temp.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return temp;
}

var x = [-3, 5, 1, 3, 2, 10, -7];

console.log(x, ridiculousApproach(x));
```